# Discovering "hidden solution" in system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

For the system of equations

$x(1-4x-y)=0$

$y(1-2y-5x)=0$,

One of the solutions is $x=1/3, y=-1/3$, but I don't see how to find it. Some help would be appreciated. I'm obviously having a gap here.

Comment: The system is satisfied if $1-4x-y=0$ and $1-2y-5x=0$. Two linear equations in two unknowns. Solve in one of the usual ways. Or note by subtraction that $x+y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
x(1-4x-y)=0 \\
y(1-2y-5x)=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x-4x^2-xy=0 \\
y-2y^2-5xy=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x=0\space\space\vee\space\space x=\frac{1-y}{4} \\
y-2y^2-5xy=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x=0\space\space\vee\space\space x=\frac{1-y}{4} \\
y-2y^2-5\cdot 0\cdot y=0\space\space\vee\space\space y-2y^2-5\cdot \frac{1-y}{4}\cdot y=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x=0\space\space\vee\space\space x=\frac{1-y}{4} \\
y-2y^2=0\space\space\vee\space\space \left(-\frac{3y}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)y=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x=0\space\space\vee\space\space x=\frac{1-y}{4} \\
y=0\vee y=\frac{1}{2}\space\space\vee\space\space y=-\frac{1}{3}\vee y=0
\end{cases}
$$

So your solutions are:

$$x=0,y=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{4},y=0$$
$$x=\frac{1}{3},y=-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$x=0,y=0$$